How to access token from headers django/react
In my backend I use set_cookie to set an access token that I need to access in my frontend but I’m not able to.
My backend using django:
# Authentication successful
            access_token = AccessToken.for_user(user)
            refresh_token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

            response = JsonResponse({'message': 'Login successful', 'tire_stock': tire_stock_data})

            # Set HTTP-only flag for both access and refresh tokens
            response.set_cookie('access_token', str(access_token), secure=True)
            response.set_cookie('refresh_token', str(refresh_token), httponly=True, secure=True)

            return response

My frontend using react:
const response = await axios.post(
        `${import.meta.env.VITE_URL}auth/login/`,
        { username: username, password: password },
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );

The response header:

I have tried response.headers['access_token'] which returned undefined. I also tried document.cookie which didnt work. I read online that I need to expose header to access it? Not sure how to do that on Django. ChatGPT said I don’t need to expose header. I was thinking of passing the token in body which would solve it but that’s not industry standard since tokens should usually be in headers. So I’m not sure how to go about it? I showed the SameSite issue incase it’s relevant which I don’t think since when going on Chrome devtools application/cookies I see the tokens there so they’re being set fine? Could SameSite cause this issue?

If I understand the problem correctly, you cannot access the token from JS.
To allow it, you need to add a setting in settings.py:
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly
